# Displaying multiple images with an ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display multiple images coming from a remote server on a single page, the page is a html file where putting php blocks wouldn't be doing anything to get thing I want

Using PHP version 5.6, the code for the php is

```
$dir = "uploads/image/dashed/";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
if ( is_file($dir. $file) ){
    echo $file;
    }
}
```

the ajax response code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'folder.php',
            success: function(data){
               $("#imageContent").html(data).append("<br/>");
               var images = data.split("\n");
                for (var i = 0, j = images.length; i < j; i++){
                   $("#imageContent").append("<img src='uploads/image/dashed/" + images[i] + "' width='300'>"); 
                }
            }
        });
});
```

all I keep getting from the server is 
1354876944ABF.jpg_MG_0085.jpg
and an empty image place holder (not two, just the one) for where the image
and the image address is showing two image names stuck together in one link

> uploads/image/dashed/1354876944ABF.jpg_MG_0085.jpg

where the response link should be on two (for this example) different lines and images where the `<img>` is on the html inside the ajax call

Comment: You are trying to split by newline, but your `echo` doesn't echo a newline character

Comment: Ok, I have tried to use th<br /> at the end of the echo statement, it does break up the line, but doesn't display the images as it is still the same

Comment: `<br />` is not `\n`

Comment: That is fair do, but since I am still noob

Comment: Echo a `\n` instead of `<br />`. Then PHP and JavaScript use matching characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
$dir = "uploads/image/dashed/";
$files = scandir($dir);
$i = 1;
$count = count($files);
foreach ($files as $file){

if(is_file($dir. $file)){
if($i == $count){
echo $file;
}else{echo $file.'|||';
   }
  }
$i++;}
```

and change `ajax` to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'folder.php',
        success: function(data){
           $("#imageContent").html(data).append("<br/>");
           var images = data.split("|||");
            for (var i = 0, j = images.length; i < j; i++){
               $("#imageContent").append("<img src='uploads/image/dashed/" + images[i] + "' width='300'>"); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

thats using `|||` as a delimiter.

**EDIT:** now it should work properly,
**EDIT2:** changed `$i = 0` order, added `$i++;` at the end

Comment: Brilliant, but it's left an extra image tag at the end

Comment: Nope, images are not found by the console in the browser

Comment: check what is the path to the images in the browser console

Comment: Just tried the one with the second edit, displays images but no change from the code

Comment: Changed the code regarding the i++ in the second edit, but no change in display

Comment: the path shown for images in the browser is the correct path?

Comment: means, does it shows `http://domain.com/uploads/image/dashed/imagename`? or its displaying a wrong path?

Comment: It does show the images and right path, but as I said first, it is showing an extra "http://domain.com/uploads/image/dashed/" (which shouldn't be there, the last one is because there is no image(s) to display as there is only two images in the folder where I am using the scandir() function

Comment: btw i added this to check if the last file the echo the file without `|||`, but note that if the last `$file` is a dir it wont work properly `if($i == $count)`,

Comment: oh, change `$i = 0` to `$i = 1`

Comment: i changed it again to fit `$i = 1` please copy the new code

Comment: np :), just accept it as the an answer and upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

`scandir()` is already giving you an array, so why not just json_encode it and return this? `unset()` any output that is not a valid file:

```
$files = scandir($dir);
$count = count($files);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ( !is_file($dir. $file) ){
        unset($files[$i]);        
    }
}

echo json_encode($files);
```

then in your success block:

```
success: function(data){
           $("#imageContent").html(data).append("<br/>");
           var i,
               json = JSON.parse(data);          
           for (i in json){
               $("#imageContent").append("<img src='uploads/image/dashed/" + json[i] + "' width='300'>"); 
            }
        }
```