# How to show images with for loops?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, for-loop

What I'm really trying to do is create a web page for a booking page, where you can rent cabins. But there are only some periods that the cabins are vacant, so I want to find which one is available at the different periods. What I succeeded was to get information for the different cabins, but I'm struggling to get the picture forward.

```js
var ferie = document.getElementById("ferie")
var parUt = document.getElementById("parUt")
var bilde = document.getElementById("bilde")
var hytter = [{
    navn: "Granstua",
    sengeplasser: 4,
    standard: "høy",
    badstue: "Ja",
    ukepris: "12 000 kr",
    enLedig: "Påske",
    bilde: "granstua.jpg"

  },
  {
    navn: "Granbo",
    sengeplasser: 6,
    standard: "Middels",
    badstue: "Nei",
    ukepris: "15 000 kr",
    ledig: "VinterFerie",
    enLedig: "Jul",
    bilde: "granbo.jpg"
  },

  {
    navn: "Granhaug",
    sengeplasser: 10,
    standard: "Høy",
    badstue: "Ja",
    ukepris: "30 000 kr",
    ledig: "VinterFerie",
    bilde: "granhaug.jpg"


  }

]

function ledigSjekk() {
  var periode = ferie.value
  var tekstUt = "oversikt over alle hyttene som er tilgjgenlig<br>"
  for (var i = 0; i < hytter.length; i++) {
    if (periode == hytter[i].ledig) {
      tekstUt += "<br>hytteNavn:" + hytter[i].navn
      tekstUt += "<br>sengeplasser:" + hytter[i].sengeplasser
      tekstUt += "<br>standard:" + hytter[i].standard
      tekstUt += "<br>badstue:" + hytter[i].badstue
      tekstUt += "<br>ukepris" + hytter[i].ukepris + "<hr>"
      bilde.src = hytter[i].bilde
    } else if (periode == hytter[i].enLedig) {
      tekstUt += "<br>hytteNavn:" + hytter[i].navn
      tekstUt += "<br>sengeplasser:" + hytter[i].sengeplasser
      tekstUt += "<br>standard:" + hytter[i].standard
      tekstUt += "<br>badstue:" + hytter[i].badstue
      tekstUt += "<br>ukepris" + hytter[i].ukepris
      bilde.src = hytter[i].bilde


    }
  }
  parUt.innerHTML = tekstUt

}
```

```html
<select class="" name="" id="ferie">
  <option>Jul</option>
  <option>VinterFerie</option>
  <option>Påske</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="ledigSjekk()" name="button">Sjekk hvilken som er ledig</button>
<p id="parUt"></p>
<img src="" id="bilde" alt="">
```

Comment: Where are the images located? Are they a URL, or are they stored in your filesystem?  If they are a URL you need to specify the URL path e.g. `https://www.something.com/granstua.jpg`; if they are on your filesystem you need to specify where they are e.g. `../img/granstua.jpg`

Comment: they are in my filesystem.

Comment: how can i contack you? Do you have instagram, facebook or something?

Comment: Depending on where they are located on your filesystem, you need to specify the relative path to the image.  So if your HTML file is at the root of your directory and your images are in an `img` folder, it would probably look something like: `./img/granstua.jpg`

Comment: i understand what you mean, and i can show one image, but there are more images i want to show.

Comment: Assuming ledigSjekk function is the one that decides the number of images, you need to use the document.createElement('IMG') in it, for each picture you need, and then append it to the DOM. take a look at this:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Comment: sheff2k1, do you hava social media?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gridster.js](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) or just refer to similar previously asked questions that have been answered.

[Displaying multiple images dynamically with Javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455618/displaying-multiple-images-dynamically-with-javascript-or-jquery)

[Displaying multiple images with an ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755284/displaying-multiple-images-with-an-ajax-response)